# Adding key/list to dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

How can I convert the following query to dictionary `Dictionary<key, List<StudentSummary>` for my following LINQ query:

In Dictionary, `Key` will taken as `first group by Key` i.e. `x.test.a` and `List<StudentSummary>` will be for whole second select in linq query.

```
private void get(baseQuery) {
    List<StudentSummary> summary = baseQuery
    .GroupBy(x =>x.test.a)
    .Select(x=>new StudentSummary {
        Name = x.key.
        StudentDetails = baseQuery
        .GroupBy(y=>y.test1.b)
        .OrderBy(y => y.key)
        .Select(y => new StudentDetails {
            studentDetailsProp1 = 10;       
            studentDetailsProp2 = 10;       
        }).ToList(),        
        TotalMarks =100;        
    }).ToList();    
}
```

Comment: I helped make your code look a bit more "compilable", but `get(baseQuery)` is beyond me. Please post a [mcve] of your problem.

Comment: I don't see any question marks. What is the problem?

Comment: baseQuery is just a collection already data using which i am constructing StudentSummary.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Maybe you want `Enumerable.ToDictionary()`? Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly what you've tried already, along with a precise explanation of what that code does and how that's different from what you want. Provide exact specification of both the input and the desired output of the code.

Comment: @immirza what the others mean is that when you provide code it is necessary that you provide code that compiles in order to help you. Additionally you should make it clear what it is that you are asking / what you want as your question is not clear there.

Comment: @ Thomas, thanks well noted. My question have enough details. All i want to use dictionary instead of list which i mentioned in the code. I don't understand why it is important to know what my baseQuery has?? Off course it has pre filtered set of records which has nothing to do with my dictionary population. Right or wrong? Was my LINQ query not clear ? What problem you see when converting it to dictionary?

Comment: @immirza if you provide code it should be compileable. For example  what type baseQuery is of is not necessary if you had not put in private void get.....   thus the methods line (as it is not relavant for the question itself in essence). List<StudentSummary> summary = baseQuery would have been enough (even that line is not necessary if you had for example said "summary is of type List<StdentSummary>" or just initialized it empty and made .... "initialization code", .... .  Only mentioning this fso that you know why ppl ask and what could be done there.

Comment: @Thomas alight. again thanks for your points and i do agree. i shall make my question clear for this and ongoing posts. cheers.